# Modifying gallery image width on Shopify New Standard Theme

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, gallery

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to modify my gallery which runs on JS Colorbox on Shopify.
My storefront link is http://chillonbroadway-2.myshopify.com/
The major problem I'm having with the gallery is whenever I make the width bigger than the default, the images inside the gallery begin to shift out of focus beginning with the 2nd slider image.  I'm convinced it's something with the javascript, I'm a beginner with the language and only know how to modify jqueries or premade scripts.

Please help!

Thanks!